# fread in data.table behaving different in Ubuntu vs Mac OSX

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I typically run two difference sessions of R.  One is RStudio Server in a Ubuntu setting and the other is locally on a Mac.  I have been reading in files using `data.table`'s `fread` function and I am getting unexpected behavior.  I receive zero errors when reading in a series of files on my Mac, but when running the same code on the Ubuntu server, I get the following errors:

A)
`Error in fread(csv, verbose = F, colClasses = list(character = 1:col.num)) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed`

B)
`Error in fread(temp[3], verbose = T, colClasses = list(character = 1:451)) : 
  Not positioned correctly after testing format of header row. ch=',`

These series of files have many columns (over 500 per table) so it is not all that easy for me to find the error manually.  Has anyone else had this problem?  Both instances are running `data.table 1.9.3`.

Here is my sessionInfo for the Ubuntu server:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_0.6.2     data.table_1.9.3  R.utils_1.32.4    R.oo_1.18.0       R.methodsS3_1.6.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1     Rcpp_0.11.2    reshape2_1.2.2 tools_3.1.0
```

And here is my `sessionInfo` for the Mac:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_0.6.2    data.table_1.9.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1   Rcpp_0.11.2  reshape2_1.4 tools_3.1.0
```

When I don't declare `colClasses`, the R-session aborts without displaying any information.

Here is the message with verbose=T for one of the datasets:

```
data <- fread(temp[1],verbose=T)

Input contains no \n. Taking this to be a filename to open
File opened, filesize is 0.002 GB
File is opened and mapped ok
Detected eol as \r only (no \n afterwards). An old Mac 9 standard, discontinued in 2002 according to Wikipedia.
Using line 30 to detect sep (the last non blank line in the first 'autostart') ... sep=','
Found 453 columns
First row with 453 fields occurs on line 1 (either column names or first row of data)
All the fields on line 1 are character fields. Treating as the column names.
Count of eol after first data row: 2723
Subtracted 0 for last eol and any trailing empty lines, leaving 2723 data rows
Type codes (   first 5 rows): 111444411444444444444441141444441111411111441414411441141411411411111111111111411114111111111411111111141111111111111414411111111411111111144111111144414111144444444411144444444444444444444444441111111111444444111144444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444414444114444411111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Type codes (+ middle 5 rows): 111444411444444444444441441444441111441144441444441441141441411411111111111141411114111111111411111111141111111111111414441111111411111111144444141444414111144444444411144444444444444444444444441111111111444444111144444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444414444114444441111111441144444414441414444444441111111111111111111111111111111111144444444441111111111114444411111111111111111111111144444444441111111111111111111111111111
Type codes (+   last 5 rows): 111444411444444444444441441444441111441144441444441441141441411411111111111141411114111111111411111111141111111111111414441111111411111111144444141444414111144444444411144444444444444444444444441111111111444444111144444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444414444114444441111111441144444414441414444444441111111111111111111111111111111111144444444441111111111114444411111111111111111111111144444444441111111111111111111111111111
Type codes: 111444411444444444444441441444441111441144441444441441141441411411111111111141411114111111111411111111141111111111111414441111111411111111144444141444414111144444444411144444444444444444444444441111111111444444111144444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444414444114444441111111441144444414441414444444441111111111111111111111111111111111144444444441111111111114444411111111111111111111111144444444441111111111111111111111111111 (after applying colClasses and integer64)
Type codes: 111444411444444444444441441444441111441144441444441441141441411411111111111141411114111111111411111111141111111111111414441111111411111111144444141444414111144444444411144444444444444444444444441111111111444444111144444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444414444114444441111111441144444414441414444444441111111111111111111111111111111111144444444441111111111114444411111111111111111111111144444444441111111111111111111111111111 (after applying drop or select (if supplied)
Allocating 453 column slots (453 - 0 dropped)
Bumping column 167 from INT to INT64 on data row 12, field contains 'no data'
Bumping column 167 from INT64 to REAL on data row 12, field contains 'no data'
Bumping column 167 from REAL to STR on data row 12, field contains 'no data'
Bumping column 169 from INT to INT64 on data row 15, field contains 'Only answered questions 1-62 in whole packet '
Bumping column 169 from INT64 to REAL on data row 15, field contains 'Only answered questions 1-62 in whole packet '
Bumping column 169 from REAL to STR on data row 15, field contains 'Only answered questions 1-62 in whole packet '
Bumping column 132 from INT to INT64 on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 132 from INT64 to REAL on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 132 from REAL to STR on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 289 from INT to INT64 on data row 152, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 289 from INT64 to REAL on data row 152, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 289 from REAL to STR on data row 152, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 290 from INT to INT64 on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 290 from INT64 to REAL on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 290 from REAL to STR on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 330 from INT to INT64 on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 330 from INT64 to REAL on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 330 from REAL to STR on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 331 from INT to INT64 on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 331 from INT64 to REAL on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 331 from REAL to STR on data row 152, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 334 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 334 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 334 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 335 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 335 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 335 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 336 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 336 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 336 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 407 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 407 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 407 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 408 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 408 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 408 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 409 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 409 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 409 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 410 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 410 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 410 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 411 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 411 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 411 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 412 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 412 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 412 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 413 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 413 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 413 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 415 from INT to INT64 on data row 153, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 415 from INT64 to REAL on data row 153, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 415 from REAL to STR on data row 153, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 375 from INT to INT64 on data row 161, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 375 from INT64 to REAL on data row 161, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 375 from REAL to STR on data row 161, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 414 from INT to INT64 on data row 161, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 414 from INT64 to REAL on data row 161, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 414 from REAL to STR on data row 161, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 36 from INT to INT64 on data row 163, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 36 from INT64 to REAL on data row 163, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 36 from REAL to STR on data row 163, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 332 from INT to INT64 on data row 169, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 332 from INT64 to REAL on data row 169, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 332 from REAL to STR on data row 169, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 333 from INT to INT64 on data row 169, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 333 from INT64 to REAL on data row 169, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 333 from REAL to STR on data row 169, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 386 from INT to INT64 on data row 170, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 386 from INT64 to REAL on data row 170, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 386 from REAL to STR on data row 170, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 427 from INT to INT64 on data row 174, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 427 from INT64 to REAL on data row 174, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 427 from REAL to STR on data row 174, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 137 from INT to INT64 on data row 178, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 137 from INT64 to REAL on data row 178, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 137 from REAL to STR on data row 178, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 92 from INT to INT64 on data row 179, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 92 from INT64 to REAL on data row 179, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 92 from REAL to STR on data row 179, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 363 from INT to INT64 on data row 182, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 363 from INT64 to REAL on data row 182, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 363 from REAL to STR on data row 182, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 385 from INT to INT64 on data row 182, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 385 from INT64 to REAL on data row 182, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 385 from REAL to STR on data row 182, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 110 from INT to INT64 on data row 185, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 110 from INT64 to REAL on data row 185, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 110 from REAL to STR on data row 185, field contains 'f'
Bumping column 51 from INT to INT64 on data row 186, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 51 from INT64 to REAL on data row 186, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 51 from REAL to STR on data row 186, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 392 from INT to INT64 on data row 193, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 392 from INT64 to REAL on data row 193, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 392 from REAL to STR on data row 193, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 353 from INT to INT64 on data row 200, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 353 from INT64 to REAL on data row 200, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 353 from REAL to STR on data row 200, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 376 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 376 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 376 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 377 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 377 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 377 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 378 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 378 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 378 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 379 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 379 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 379 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 380 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 380 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 380 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 381 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 381 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 381 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 382 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 382 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 382 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 383 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 383 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 383 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 384 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 384 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 384 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 393 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 393 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 393 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 394 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 394 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 394 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 395 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 395 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 395 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 396 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 396 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 396 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 397 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 397 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 397 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 398 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 398 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 398 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 399 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 399 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 399 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 400 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 400 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 400 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 401 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 401 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 401 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 402 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 402 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 402 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 403 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 403 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 403 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 404 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 404 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 404 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 405 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 405 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 405 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 406 from INT to INT64 on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 406 from INT64 to REAL on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 406 from REAL to STR on data row 201, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 357 from INT to INT64 on data row 208, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 357 from INT64 to REAL on data row 208, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 357 from REAL to STR on data row 208, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 362 from INT to INT64 on data row 212, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 362 from INT64 to REAL on data row 212, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 362 from REAL to STR on data row 212, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 428 from INT to INT64 on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 428 from INT64 to REAL on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 428 from REAL to STR on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 429 from INT to INT64 on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 429 from INT64 to REAL on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 429 from REAL to STR on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 430 from INT to INT64 on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 430 from INT64 to REAL on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 430 from REAL to STR on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 431 from INT to INT64 on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 431 from INT64 to REAL on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 431 from REAL to STR on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 432 from INT to INT64 on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 432 from INT64 to REAL on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 432 from REAL to STR on data row 214, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 355 from INT to INT64 on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 355 from INT64 to REAL on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 355 from REAL to STR on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 358 from INT to INT64 on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 358 from INT64 to REAL on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 358 from REAL to STR on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 359 from INT to INT64 on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 359 from INT64 to REAL on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 359 from REAL to STR on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 361 from INT to INT64 on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 361 from INT64 to REAL on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 361 from REAL to STR on data row 331, field contains 'nr'
Bumping column 99 from INT to INT64 on data row 358, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 99 from INT64 to REAL on data row 358, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 99 from REAL to STR on data row 358, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 107 from INT to INT64 on data row 419, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 107 from INT64 to REAL on data row 419, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 107 from REAL to STR on data row 419, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 139 from INT to INT64 on data row 464, field contains 'h'
Bumping column 139 from INT64 to REAL on data row 464, field contains 'h'
Bumping column 139 from REAL to STR on data row 464, field contains 'h'
Bumping column 117 from INT to INT64 on data row 468, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 117 from INT64 to REAL on data row 468, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 117 from REAL to STR on data row 468, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 134 from INT to INT64 on data row 468, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 134 from INT64 to REAL on data row 468, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 134 from REAL to STR on data row 468, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 123 from INT to INT64 on data row 521, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 123 from INT64 to REAL on data row 521, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 123 from REAL to STR on data row 521, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 70 from INT to INT64 on data row 546, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 70 from INT64 to REAL on data row 546, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 70 from REAL to STR on data row 546, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 3 from INT to INT64 on data row 554, field contains '184943; quest 184946'
Bumping column 3 from INT64 to REAL on data row 554, field contains '184943; quest 184946'
Bumping column 3 from REAL to STR on data row 554, field contains '184943; quest 184946'
Bumping column 100 from INT to INT64 on data row 618, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 100 from INT64 to REAL on data row 618, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 100 from REAL to STR on data row 618, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 60 from INT to INT64 on data row 639, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 60 from INT64 to REAL on data row 639, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 60 from REAL to STR on data row 639, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 72 from INT to INT64 on data row 722, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 72 from INT64 to REAL on data row 722, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 72 from REAL to STR on data row 722, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 2 from INT to INT64 on data row 743, field contains '1430 and 7430'
Bumping column 2 from INT64 to REAL on data row 743, field contains '1430 and 7430'
Bumping column 2 from REAL to STR on data row 743, field contains '1430 and 7430'
Bumping column 90 from INT to INT64 on data row 869, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 90 from INT64 to REAL on data row 869, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 90 from REAL to STR on data row 869, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 135 from INT to INT64 on data row 869, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 135 from INT64 to REAL on data row 869, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 135 from REAL to STR on data row 869, field contains 'd'
Bumping column 214 from INT to INT64 on data row 964, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 214 from INT64 to REAL on data row 964, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 214 from REAL to STR on data row 964, field contains 'NR'
Bumping column 24 from INT to INT64 on data row 989, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 24 from INT64 to REAL on data row 989, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 24 from REAL to STR on data row 989, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 106 from INT to INT64 on data row 1150, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 106 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1150, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 106 from REAL to STR on data row 1150, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 195 from INT to INT64 on data row 1181, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 195 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1181, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 195 from REAL to STR on data row 1181, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 102 from INT to INT64 on data row 1261, field contains 'g'
Bumping column 102 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1261, field contains 'g'
Bumping column 102 from REAL to STR on data row 1261, field contains 'g'
Bumping column 88 from INT to INT64 on data row 1265, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 88 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1265, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 88 from REAL to STR on data row 1265, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 168 from INT to INT64 on data row 1270, field contains ' pg. 15 respondent wrote ""peso al nacer 4.025 kg"""'
Bumping column 168 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1270, field contains ' pg. 15 respondent wrote ""peso al nacer 4.025 kg"""'
Bumping column 168 from REAL to STR on data row 1270, field contains ' pg. 15 respondent wrote ""peso al nacer 4.025 kg"""'
Bumping column 211 from INT to INT64 on data row 1270, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 211 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1270, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 211 from REAL to STR on data row 1270, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 212 from INT to INT64 on data row 1270, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 212 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1270, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 212 from REAL to STR on data row 1270, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 202 from INT to INT64 on data row 1273, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 202 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1273, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 202 from REAL to STR on data row 1273, field contains 'c'
Bumping column 213 from INT to INT64 on data row 1273, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 213 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1273, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 213 from REAL to STR on data row 1273, field contains 'a'
Bumping column 337 from INT to INT64 on data row 1273, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 337 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1273, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 337 from REAL to STR on data row 1273, field contains 'b'
Bumping column 136 from INT to INT64 on data row 1412, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 136 from INT64 to REAL on data row 1412, field contains 'e'
Bumping column 136 from REAL to STR on data row 1412, field contains 'e'
Error in fread(temp[1], verbose = T) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: How are you able to run `data.table 1.9.3`? The latest stable release is `1.9.2`.

Comment: ```data.table_1.9.3```

Comment: Hi. Please run again with `verbose=TRUE` and paste the full output. Hopefully that'll give me enough of a clue to fix it. And does it work without specifying `colClasses`?

Comment: Just added the results for ```verbose=T``` (I edited the results to conform to the 30000 character limit of a stack overflow post).  When I don't specify ```colClassses```, my R-session aborts for some of the data tables I am trying to bring in.  My data does have fields with quotes and the data is from Mexico, so there are accents and tildes scattered about.  I am unsure if that matters.  If I dont specify ```colClasses``, the R-session aborts in both Mac OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Notice the line near the top: `Detected eol as \r only (no \n afterwards). An old Mac 9 standard, discontinued in 2002 according to Wikipedia.`  Is the file more than a decade old?  Otherwise, looks like a problem detecting the line ending. Are there embedded `\r` in fields perhaps? Can you send me the file (it looks small) to `maintainer("data.table")`?

Comment: Thanks @MattDowle.  I just sent the email.  This is data that was collected in Mexico over the past few years.  It is not that old, but it certainly could have been input using very old software.